# Extracting Data between Parentheses in R

Tags: r

Raw Data:

```
550 LEE DR BATON ROUGE, LA 70802 (30.399995, -91.15418)
2810 SCENIC HW BATON ROUGE, LA 70805 (30.473461, -91.168378)
11201 MEAD RD BATON ROUGE, LA
550 LEE DR BATON ROUGE, LA 70802 (30.399995, -91.15418)
2810 SCENIC HW BATON ROUGE, LA 70805 (30.473461, -91.168378)
11201 MEAD RD BATON ROUGE, LA
```

For R, I am trying to set up a code that will give me the following geolocation results (remember I don't want the NA records gone but to just leave it blank):

```
(30.399995, -91.15418)
(30.473461, -91.168378)
NA    
(30.399995, -91.15418)    
(30.473461, -91.168378)    
NA
```

I tried:

```
ag <- data.frame(sub(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "\\1", 
geolocation$test.Geolocation, perl=TRUE))
ag
```

but to no avail. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
fun <- function(x){
  res <- regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\(.*\\)", x))[[1]]
  ifelse(length(res) == 0, NA_character_, res)
}

unlist(sapply(geolocation$test.Geolocation, fun))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I needed. I appreciate it.